# Using Custom Hook with search parameters

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

next it's a code that uses a HOC for showing some components while a fetch (with a custom hook) to an API REST is made.

From useSearchParams() I get the query string that will be used in fetching data.

The issue here is that when the component is rendered useFetch is executed but the search parameter (param) is not ready, then fetch is executed with null value.

```
const withLoading = (WrappedComponent) => {
    const HocComponent = ({ ...props }) => {
        const [urlParams, setUrlParams] = useSearchParams()
        const [param, setParam] = useState()
        useEffect(() => {
            console.log(urlParams.get("text"));
            setParam(urlParams.get("text"))
        }, [urlParams])
        const { data, loading, error } = useFetch("api_server", "/articles", { 'text': param })
        if (loading) return (
            <div className="grid grid-cols-6">
                {Array(6).map(el => <ProductPulse />)}
            </div>
        )
        return <WrappedComponent data={data} error={error} />
    }
    return HocComponent
}
```

Any comments on how to solve this issue using the hook useFetch?

I've tried many different ways without any luck.

I'm specting to use the custom hook useFetch in this scenario.

Comment: Can you add a `skip` option for the `useFetch` hook? Like this `skip: !!param`. If `skip` is true, then don't do anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue with the current implementation is that you are caching the `text` queryString parameter in state, which delays the `param` state value being available by ***at least*** one render cycle.

The fix is trivial though, just consume the `text` queryString parameter directly, there's no need for any `param` state.

Example:

```
const withLoading = Component => props => {
  const [urlParams] = useSearchParams();

  const param = urlParams.get("text");

  const { data, loading, error } = useFetch(
    "api_server",
    "/articles",
    { text: param },
  );

  if (loading) {
    return (
      <div className="grid grid-cols-6">
        {Array(6).map((el, key) => <ProductPulse key={key} />)}
      </div>
    );
  }

  return <Component data={data} error={error} />;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Your API has been called when `HocComponent` gets rendered, so it won't wait for your API response.

Ideally, you should have `loading` state to wait for the fetch completed, and you also can set `data` state instead of `param` state in `useEffect` whenever `urlParams` has changed.

```
const withLoading = (WrappedComponent) => {
    const HocComponent = ({ ...props }) => {
        const [urlParams, setUrlParams] = useSearchParams()
        //`response` state to listen to API response changes
        const [response, setResponse] = useState({ data: null, error: null, loading: true })
        useEffect(() => {
            console.log(urlParams.get("text"));
            const param = urlParams.get("text");
            //`urlParams` gets changed and not undefined, we call API here
            if(urlParams.get("text")) {
               const { data, loading, error } = useFetch("api_server", "/articles", { 'text': param });
               setResponse({ data, loading, error })
            }

        }, [urlParams])

        const { loading, data, error } = response
        
        if (loading) return (
            <div className="grid grid-cols-6">
                {Array(6).map(el => <ProductPulse />)}
            </div>
        )
        return <WrappedComponent data={data} error={error} />
    }
    return HocComponent
}
```